# Flutter Text and text color not updated after Hot reload

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I am trying to change the text and it's color in hot reload

```
void main() {
  runApp(new getMyView();
}

Center getMyView() {
  return Center(
    child: Text("Nepali",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber),
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr),
  );
}
```

But when I **change** "`Nepali`" to "`Nepal`" or I change `Colors.amber` to `Colors.white` and **hot reload**, it does **not get reflected** in the emulator.

I have to **"Full Restart"** the app to see the changes

Comment: `main` is only ever executed once.  If you want to use hot reload you should change the function `getMyView` to a widget instead.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Problem** : As @JonahWilliams described `main()` is  executed **only once** in the whole app session.

**Solution** : Do the **UI change** inside **Widget**

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyView());
}

class MyView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center(
      child: Text("Nepali",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Flutter Hot reload](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/hot-reload) As described here HotReload re-builds the widget tree, so it ececutes build method, but not main.

Answer (score 0):

StatelessWidget is required for hot reload.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Text(
                'Container 2',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: const TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.red),
              ),
            )
          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).